# QGIS 3 - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

everytime when i launch QGIS3 this error appears.

Does anybody have an solution for that problem?

[image]

Comment: Please always provide errors as text rather than pictures.

Comment: Perhaps this link https://github.com/okfn/ckanext-inspire/issues/4 can help. You should use **pip3** for installing this missing dependence.